# working with tFileOutputExcel and tExtractJSONFields in Talend

Tags: json, talend

I am trying to copy the data from my json file into an excel file(tFileInputExcel) which has a column named store.

```
{
   "resultat":[
      {
         "codeProduit":"78",
         "nomCat":"nomCat11",
         "typeCat":"typeCat11"
      },
      {
         "codeProduit":"82",
         "nomCat":"nomCat21",
         "typeCat":"typeCat21"
      },
      {
         "codeProduit":"69",
         "nomCat":"nomCat31",
         "typeCat":"typeCat31"
      }
   ]
}
```

My excel file having a column is in input and I want to copy the result of my json file (nameCat and typCat) into my excel file taking the data from my first excel file.

So I want to have in my tFileOutputExcel three columns : store, category and category type.

But I can't copy the data from the first excel file to the other excel file (tFileOutputExcel) above my talend job

[mytalendJob](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZ6Q3.png)

I want to link my tFileInputExcel_1 which contains the store column with the result obtained from the json file in tFileInputJson_1 contained in the file tFileOutputExcel_1.  But with the first schema, the tMap component doesn't allow me to copy the column from tFileInputExcel1 to tFileOutputExcel_1.
Can I do it differently to copy the data from my file tFileInputExcel_1 and copy it in my file tFileOuputExcel_1 then add the data from the json

Comment: In your screenshot, your two subjobs are not linked.  Do you have a key to join flow from JSON and flow from Excel file ? Your post is lacking details to answer you

Comment: Hi @Corentin, with the first schema, the tMap component doesn't allow me to copy the column from tFileInputExcel1 to tFileOutputExcel_1.
Can I do it differently to copy the data from my file tFileInputExcel_1 and copy it in my file

Comment: did you try to link to your tMap tFileInputExcel_1 as the main flow, and tExtractJsonFields as the lookup flow, then one single output to your tFileOutputExcel_1 ?

Comment: Hi @Corentin, I can't do it. When i select tMap and right click,select row -> new output(Main) and select it to link to tExtractJsonFields, i can't. Can show by by do it with an image please

Comment: you will have two different INPUTS for your tMap  : tFileInputExcel as the main flow, tFileInputJson+tExtractJsonFields as the lookup flow. Checkout basic tMap documentation to learn more about this component, as it is a crucial component to work with in Talend . https://help.talend.com/r/rKQwl90bzZmLu76Z4mTjIA/iVohqJA81Ts00ChDugvhnQ